# Flutter 2 - Dark theme state

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, themes

I'm new with Flutter and I'm building my first Flutter 2 project from scratch.

I'm having an issue with ->
`themeMode: (state is ChangeThemeSuccess) ? (state.isDarkMode) ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.light,`

It says that `(state.isDarkMode)` is not recognized

How can I fix this ?

Thank you

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Initialize all bloc provider used on this entire application here
   return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
         // this bloc used for feature - change language
         BlocProvider<LanguageCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => LanguageCubit(),
         ),
         // this bloc used to change theme on feature list
         BlocProvider<ThemeCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => ThemeCubit(),
         ),
     ],
     
     child: InitialLanguage(
        child: BlocBuilder<LanguageCubit, LanguageState>(
           builder: (context, state) {
              return MaterialApp(
                 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
                 scrollBehavior: CustomScrollBehavior(),
                 title: appName,
                 theme: ThemeData.light(),
                 darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
                 themeMode: (state is ChangeThemeSuccess)
                    ? (state.isDarkMode)
                    ? ThemeMode.dark
                    : ThemeMode.light
                    : ThemeMode.light,
          
             // below is used for language feature
             supportedLocales: const [
                Locale('en', 'US'),
                Locale('sv', 'SE'),
             ],
             
             localizationsDelegates: const [
                AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
             ],
             // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
             locale: (state is ChangeLanguageSuccess)
                 ? state.locale
                 : const Locale('en', 'US'),
             home: const Navigation(),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

theme_state.dart

```
@immutable
abstract class ThemeState {}

class ThemeInitial extends ThemeState {}

class ChangeThemeSuccess extends ThemeState {
   final bool isDarkMode;
   ChangeThemeSuccess(this.isDarkMode);
}
```

Comment: BlocBuilder<LanguageCubit, LanguageState>  this line is the problem try change LanguageState to ChangeThemeSuccess

Answer (score 0):

```
        child: BlocBuilder<LanguageCubit, LanguageState>(
```

your BlocBuilder is watching LanguageState instead of ThemeState

Comment: Is there no way to fix this without changing it from watching - LanguageState
Can I not somehow make it so that BlocBuilder watches both Language and theme ?